# keras-vis visualize saliency issue

Tags: keras

I am trying to replicate the results from: https://github.com/raghakot/keras-vis/blob/master/examples/mnist/attention.ipynb to produce a saliency map of zero. I put in the exact same code, and as suggested, used:

```
from vis.visualization import visualize_saliency
from vis.utils import utils
from keras import activations

# Utility to search for layer index by name. 
# Alternatively we can specify this as -1 since it corresponds to the last layer.
layer_idx = utils.find_layer_idx(model, 'preds')

# Swap softmax with linear
model.layers[layer_idx].activation = activations.linear
model = utils.apply_modifications(model)

grads = visualize_saliency(model, layer_idx, filter_indices=class_idx,seed_input=x_test[idx])
# Plot with 'jet' colormap to visualize as a heatmap.
plt.imshow(grads, cmap='jet')
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: conv2d_1_input_3:0 is both fed and fetched.
```

I looked elsewhere and have seen suggestions to upgrade keras-vis, I have done this but the same error shows up. The error appears to be in

```
grads = visualize_saliency(model, layer_idx, filter_indices=class_idx,seed_input=x_test[idx])
```

as when I comment this line out, no error shows.

**How can I solve this?**

Answer (score 4):

It's solved! If anyone has this problem, use: 
    pip install git+git://github.com/raghakot/keras-vis.git --upgrade --no-deps

Comment: fixed it for me. Thanks